# Python error: one of the arguments is required

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I'm trying to run a code from github that uses Python to classify images but I'm getting an error.

here is the code:

```
import argparse as ap
import cv2
import imutils 
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from scipy.cluster.vq import *



# Get the path of the testing set
parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument("-t", "--testingSet", help="Path to testing Set")
group.add_argument("-i", "--image", help="Path to image")
parser.add_argument('-v',"--visualize", action='store_true')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

# Get the path of the testing image(s) and store them in a list
image_paths = []
if args["testingSet"]:
    test_path = args["testingSet"]
    try:
         testing_names = os.listdir(test_path)
    except OSError:
        print "No such directory {}\nCheck if the file exists".format(test_path)
        exit()
for testing_name in testing_names:
        dir = os.path.join(test_path, testing_name)
        class_path = imutils.imlist(dir)
        image_paths+=class_path
    else:
        image_paths = [args["image"]]
```

and this is the error message I'm getting

```
usage: getClass.py [-h]
               (- C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/iris/bag-of-words-master/dataset/test TESTINGSET | - C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/iris/bag-of-words-master/dataset/test/test_1.jpg IMAGE)
               [- C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/iris/bag-of-words-master/dataset]
getClass.py: error: one of the arguments - C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/iris/bag-of-words-master/dataset/test/--testingSet - C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/iris/bag-of-words-master/dataset/test/test_1.jpg/--image is required
```

can you please help me with this? where and how should I write the file path?

Comment: what is the exact command you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error your own program is issuing. The message is not about the file path but about the number of arguments. This line

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
```

says that only one of your command-line arguments (`-t`, `-i`) is permitted. But it appears from the error message that you are supplying both `--testingSet` and `--image` on your command line.

Since you only have 3 arguments, I have to wonder if you really need argument groups at all.

To get your command line to work, drop the mutually-exclusive group and add the arguments to the parser directly.

```
parser.add_argument("-t", "--testingSet", help="Path to testing Set")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--image", help="Path to image")
parser.add_argument('-v',"--visualize", action='store_true')
```